# How can i check that the application is compatible with windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2013, serial-port, compatibility, microcontroller, windows-10-desktop

An application, consists basically on a communication between a microcontroller and a pc, is running perfectely on Windows 7 64 bits. Since i have windows 10 installed, the application doesn t work anymore. Even the serial communication isn t established. ( an error shown that the application can not establish the communication) 
I have verified the microcontroller with other Terminal running on Windows and no Problem within. Also i think that the Problem could be on the Code, the application was created with visual Studio, well i don t have any experience with visual Studio,so that i would ask you if there is a way to check that this application for instance will not work on Windows 10!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have the code for the application?  Was it made by a third-party?  Is it under support?  Have you set it up on Windows 10 according to the exact directions for it?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, i have the source Code but i am unfamiliar with, i have compiled the source Code in wind 10 and the procedure was done without Problem, in Computer's device Manager after installing the Driver no error appears! so that i have thought that may be an error of compatibility and i would ask someone from the familiar users and developpers of such application, is there any method to check?

Answer (score 0):

You indicate that the application will run, therefore it is unlikely that the application is incompatible with Windows 10.   You're getting an error saying that the application is unable to communicate with the serial port, so the application is opening. Most applications which flat out won't work with Win 10 use older, unsupported versions of .Net or expect a FAT filesystem and simply won't run.

This suggests that Windows 10 did not have a native driver for your serial port.  This is not too shocking; the older pin serial ports currently see exclusive use and are replaced (for most users) by USB-connecting components.  I would check the computer's Device Manager.  If you don't see any serial ports there, or see them but with an error, Win 10 probably did not have the driver required.   From there I would contact the motherboard or serial bus card manufacturer for updated drivers, if they exist.

Comment: thank you for your answer, for the Serial Adapter i have installed the Driver and in computer's device Manager, no Problem or error appears! I have the source Code of this application and i am not familiar with such application! so that i have thought the fault could be an error of compatibility!